# UIKit Slideshow last slider animation gets delayed

Tags: jquery, uikit, css-animations

I have a UIKit Slideshow with six slides that has different widths and are all shown in an infinite-looped slideshow like this:

[image]

I change their `left` position and their `width` when the slider goes to the next one, but the sixth slider always gets delayed.

[Here's my codepen to demo it](https://codepen.io/jonacornejo/pen/xxyNYgb?editors=1010)

Here's the jQuery that I keep polishing

```
// active slide
$(desktopSlideItem).eq(activeSlideIndex).css({ 'left': '0%' }).addClass('zindex-active');
// slide 2
$(desktopSlideItem).eq(nextSlideIndex).css({ 'left': 'calc(100% - 500px)', 'z-index': '-2' });
// slide 3
$(desktopSlideItem).eq((nextSlideIndex + 1) % totalSlides).css({ 'left': 'calc(100% - 360px)', 'z-index': '-1' });
// slide 4
$(desktopSlideItem).eq((nextSlideIndex + 2) % totalSlides).css({ 'left': 'calc(100% - 270px)', 'z-index': '0' });
// slide 5
$(desktopSlideItem).eq((nextSlideIndex + 3) % totalSlides).css({ 'left': 'calc(100% - 180px)', 'z-index': '1' });

// slide 6 <--- KEEPS GETTING DELAYED
$(desktopSlideItem).eq((nextSlideIndex + 4) % totalSlides).hide().css(
    { 'left': '94%', 'transform': 'translate3d(94%, 0, 0)', 'transition-duration': '300ms', 'opacity': '0' }
).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300).addClass('zindex');
```

I think it's because the z-index only gets applied afterwards, but I don't know why when I use jQuery's `.css('z-index', '-3')`, it does not work so I only use `addClass` for it.

What can I do to fix this?